# Running separate EC2 instance for API & webapp/website is good idea?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The goal behind doing this, is any one instance down other service will keep active.

Eg. If website instance down due to heavy traffic or any reason then API instance will work as it is and mobile/desktop app will working smooth without any hurdles and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I can say **Yes** and based on AWS best practice, we better have a **Loose Coupling** architecture.

For example: You have 1 EC2 instance for API, 1 EC2 instance for Webapp.

If Webapp instance reaches its usage of CPU or Memory, you can scale it with **Auto-Scaling** immediately which will prevent downtime. While API instance does not require any upgrade since the usage is below the utilization.

Comment: thanks for agree on this :) 
But I like to wait for more feedback from experts!
Because for me its big decision as going to do it for 5 projects, so total instance will be there as per this plan.